# How can you simulate a temporary network outage of a VM lasting a few minutes without systematically losing it?

Tags: networking, 20.04, shutdown, testing

How can you simulate a temporary network outage of a VM lasting a few minutes without systematically losing it?

I've tried this command on my VM for testing purposes, but each time it's run, my VM can't be reached and needs to be rebooted.

```
sudo ip link set eth0 down && sleep 600 && sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

If anyone has any ideas, thank you in advance.

Comment: you checked after 10+ minutes, and the VM still couldn't be reached?

Comment: did you change your sudo timeout? you might need a new sudo password by the time 10 minutes are up. Try this by sleeping for 5 seconds, see if that works.

Comment: I tried with 5 seconds the VM becomes unreachable. I had to restart it.